# Stop BeautifulSoup from removing whitespace

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, whitespace

BeautifulSoup is removing whitespace between before newlines tags:

```
print BeautifulSoup("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><section>    \n</section>")
```

The code above prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<section>
</section>
```

Notice that the four spaces after the section tag are missing! Interestingly, if I do:

```
print BeautifulSoup("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><section>a    \n</section>")
```

I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<section>a    
</section>
```

The four spaces after 'a' are now present! How can I get the four spaces to show in the original print statement?

Comment: eliminate the BeautifulSoup constructor?

Comment: `In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: print BeautifulSoup("<html> </html>")
<html> </html>`

Comment: Could you replace all spaces in the string with `&#32;`?

Comment: @hd1: ha, well this was the simplest example of what's causing me a headache on much large HTML file.

Comment: @TheDude: I think I may go with a solution where I replace all spaces with some innocuous string like "THIS_IS_A_SPACE". Strangely, if I replace the space with "&#32;" I get "<html><body><p> </p></body></html>" printed out.

Comment: @Naijaba pass `html.parser` to the constructor: `BeautifulSoup('your html here', 'html.parser')`.

Comment: My bad, I actually am dealing with XML data. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could try replacing all `<section>...</section>` with `<pre>...</section>` before parsing. BeautifulSoup would then fully preserve the spaces. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><section>    \n</section>"
html = re.sub(r'(\</?)(section)(\>)', r'\1pre\3', html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

print repr(soup.pre.text)    # repr used to show where the spaces are
```

Giving you:

```
u'    \n'
```