# How to preserve spaces and indents while parsing a html file with bs4?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a bookmarks file exported from Chrome. The contents looks like this below

```
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<!-- This is an automatically generated file.
     It will be read and overwritten.
     DO NOT EDIT! -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Bookmarks</H1>
<DL><p>
    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1598912308" LAST_MODIFIED="1622706295" PERSONAL_TOOLBAR_FOLDER="true">Bookmarks bar</H3>
    <DL><p>
        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1599868499" LAST_MODIFIED="1622998728">情報工学</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><A HREF="https://event.hackhub.com/" ADD_DATE="1582945343" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">HackHub</A>
            <DT><A HREF="http://nifty.stanford.edu/" ADD_DATE="1582947306">Nifty Assignments</A>
            <DT><A HREF="http://usaco.org/" ADD_DATE="1582948827">USACO</A>
...
```

What I want to do is to modify links (href) inside `<a>` tags.

My code looks like this

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BOOKMARKS_FILE = 'bookmarks_6_8_21.html'

BASE_URLS = [
    'https://somepage.com/id/'
]

with open(BOOKMARKS_FILE, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')

def get_uuid(int_id):
    uuid = int_id + 1
    return uuid

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    url = link['href']
    for base_url in BASE_URLS:
        if url.startswith(base_url):
            id = int(re.search(r'\d+', url).group()) # extract an integer id after https://somepage.com/id/...
            uuid = get_uuid(id)
            new_url = base_url + uuid
            print(f'New url: {new_url}', end='\n\n')
            link['href'] = new_url

with open('Modified_' + BOOKMARKS_FILE, 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

Unfortunately, the modified bookmarks file doesn't contain the original indentation. So when I tried to import it to Chrome, all folders I created are gone. Is there any way I can preserve indentation from the original file?

---

Using @smci's link, I decided to gave it a shot. I replaced this line

```
with open(BOOKMARKS_FILE, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
```

with

```
with open(BOOKMARKS_FILE, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    htm = f.read()
    htm = re.sub(r'(\</?)(DL)(\>)', r'\1pre\3', htm)
    htm = re.sub(r'(\</?)(p)(\>)', r'\1pre\3', htm)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htm, 'html.parser')
    with open('Modified_xx_' + BOOKMARKS_FILE, 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
        f.write(str(soup))
```

I checked the output file and I still don't get the result I expected. The bottom of the output file is a mess

```
        <dt><a add_date="1600302193" href="javascript:void(window.open('https://web.archive.org/web/*/'+document.location.href));">Wayback</a>
        <dt><a add_date="1600302244" href="javascript:void(window.open('https://web.archive.org/save/'+location.href));">Wayback Save</a>
    </dt></dt></dt></dt></pre><pre>
</pre><pre>
</pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre></dt></pre></pre>
```

Comment: Hmm. Instead of `soup.find_all('a')` I suspect you'll need to roll your own regex and explicitly capture whitespace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop BeautifulSoup from removing whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000658/stop-beautifulsoup-from-removing-whitespace)

Comment: @smci see my edit

Comment: I tried to write you a regex but I don't have an example Windows Chrome bookmarks file. Can you link to one? Anyway, your answer is manually write a regex for '<a>' tags with a capture group for the whitespace.

Comment: Don't repeatedly write out `f.write(str(soup))` in your solution! Use a regex to find just the link, then write the link. Not all of `soup`! Anyway, just use `print()` statements until you've debugged this.

Comment: @smci [Here](https://pastebin.pl/view/391bac7a).

Comment: Never mind. I figured out the solution.

Comment: You can simply replace attributes using beautifulsoup which keeps the html structure. read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/beautifulsoup-modifying-the-tree/)